# JavaScript validation on Tiny MCE text editor

Tags: php, javascript

I want to validate (empty check) a Tiny MCE text editor using JavaScript. I have used the normal empty check function, but it's not working. Also I want to know how validate empty check in FCk editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following in your JavaScript:

```
if(tinyMCE.get("chatContent_field").getContent()==''){
   alert("Please enter the text.");
   return false;
}
```

where "chatContent_field" is id of your text area.

Comment: many tks. i am very curious to know this in the case of FCK editor. can you please tell me?
 once again very thanks

Comment: ya it's in the case for tinyMCE WYSWYG Editor. is it working for u?

Comment: ya, it's working for me. Thanks. Also i need to validate a FCk editor. Is there is any other method to validate(empty) Fckeditor? Please Reply for this..

Answer (score 0):

The editor should put its content in the textarea it's installed upon, but it might do it after You check. Try using firebug to see what Your editor does to the textarea it covers.

If You want to check directly You have to find the iframe within the editor and access its content.